# problems with create tab - android

Tags: android, tabs

I need a menu with 3 tabs.

I have the following android code, which works:

```
        tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabSpec newActivity = tabHost.newTabSpec("A");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,A.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        intent.putExtra("age", String.valueOf(age));

        newActivity.setIndicator("A", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a))
                    .setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(createTab(B.class, HOME_TAB_ID, "B", R.drawable.h));

        tabHost.addTab(newActivity);

        tabHost.addTab(createTab(C, MORE_TAB_ID, "C", R.drawable.c));
```

Class B and Class C:

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class B extends Activity{

}
```

WHY THE MIDDLE TAB HAS A DIFFERENT COLOR compared with the first and the last tab?

I need all 3 tabs to look the same. I need the middle tab to have the same color - shape as the first and third one?

Comment: more input please. we cant just imagine whats inside class B/C

Comment: it's not important what class A/B/C holds. I am interested in the way the tabs look if I use createTab compared with that newActivity

Comment: What is drawable a,b,c is that identical

Comment: They are not identical but you can put the same image.You can even not put any drawable:). As I said it's about the color of the tabs.